# python variable body API

Tags: python, api

Good Morning,

I need to understand how to insert a variable into this variable (CHANGEME).

payload = "{\n\t"client": {\n\t\t"clientId": "name"\n\t},\n\t"contentFieldOption": {\n\t\t"returnLinkedContents": false,\n\t\t"returnLinkedCategories": false,\n\t\t"returnEmbedCodes": false,\n\t\t"returnThumbnailUrl": false,\n\t\t"returnItags": false,\n\t\t"returnAclInfo": false,\n\t\t"returnImetadata": false,\n\t\t"ignoreITagCombining": false,\n\t\t"returnTotalResults": true\n\t},\n\t"criteria": {\n\t\t"linkedCategoryOp": {\n\t\t\t"linkedCategoryIds": [\n\t\t\t\t" CHANGEME ",\n\t\t\t\t"!_*TRASH*"\n\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t"cascade": true\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t"numberOfresults": 50,\n\t"offset": 0,\n\t"orderBy": "creationDate_A"\n}"

It is part of the body to be inserted inside API POST request.
I have tried various alternatives, but to no avail it led me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to hack this string with regexes; you'll end up with invalid data in no time. Use `json.loads()` to convert it into a dictionary, find the key `CHANGEME`, and do whatever you need to do (which you do not really explain).

```
>>> paydict = json.loads(payload)
>>> print(json.dumps(paydict, indent=4)
{
    "criteria": {
        "linkedCategoryOp": {
            "linkedCategoryIds": [
                " CHANGEME ",
                "!_TRASH"
                ...
```

API objects usually have a consistent structure, so your variable is probably always in the list `paydict["criteria"]["linkedCategoryOp"]["linkedCategoryIds"]`. Find the index of `" CHANGEME "` in this list, and take it from there.

Comment: Found it, but I do not understand how to replace the parameter.
Since I have to make many calls, that parameter will change every time.

Comment: Many calls using variations of this dictionary? Once you know where to put the changing data, just modify the same place over and over. If you don't understand how to set a value there, maybe edit your question to explain what you want the data to look like for the different callls -- it's not too clear to me yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **re**  - Python's regular expressions module :

```
import re

payload = '{\n\t"client": {\n\t\t"clientId": "name"\n\t},\n\t"contentFieldOption": {\n\t\t"returnLinkedContents": false,\n\t\t"returnLinkedCategories": false,\n\t\t"returnEmbedCodes": false,\n\t\t"returnThumbnailUrl": false,\n\t\t"returnItags": false,\n\t\t"returnAclInfo": false,\n\t\t"returnImetadata": false,\n\t\t"ignoreITagCombining": false,\n\t\t"returnTotalResults": true\n\t},\n\t"criteria": {\n\t\t"linkedCategoryOp": {\n\t\t\t"linkedCategoryIds": [\n\t\t\t\t" CHANGEME ",\n\t\t\t\t"!_TRASH"\n\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t"cascade": true\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t"numberOfresults": 50,\n\t"offset": 0,\n\t"orderBy": "creationDate_A"\n}'
payload = re.sub("\n|\t","",payload).strip() # do some cleanup
payload = re.sub("\s+CHANGEME\s+","NEW VALUE",payload) # Replace the value
print(payload) # CHANGEME is replaced with NEW VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple string replace to swap "CHANGEME" with something else.

```
new_str = 'IMCHANGED'
payload.replace('CHANGEME', new_str)
```

This solves your stated problem, unless there are extra constraints about what the payload looks like (right now you're assuming it's a string, or how many times the word CHANGEME occurs). Please clarify if that is the case.